# git worktree is invalid, how to correct this with git commands

Tags: git

I copy pasted a git repository from windows to linux, from a shared directory, to a standard one. And now, any `git` command returns the error:

```
fatal: Invalid path '/shared': No such file or directory.
```

I tracked down the issue to a vestigial parameter from `.git/config` which defines:

```
[core]
    worktree = //shared/directory/source/project
```

Indeed, under linux, this dir does not exist nor is a valid path... I could solve the issue by deleting the incriminated line. But I couldn't find a single git command to reset this in a cleaner manner.

Comment: `git config` is the general-purpose command to tweak those files, but mostly editing them is fine too.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522089/how-can-i-copy-my-git-repository-from-my-windows-machine-to-a-linux-machine-via) help? It's about exporting/importing a Git repo with `git bundle` :)

Comment: Why would there be a single dedicated command to fix up your worktree path? Just use `git config` to fix your config.

Comment: What the OP tries to achieve is impossible, the correct ways to export/import Git repositories across platforms are git clone or bundle.

Comment: @Useless why wouldn't git solve this issue automatically since this worktree seems to contains only the current directory ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `core.worktree` setting is [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreworktree).

If you want to change it using a Git command, use `git config core.worktree new-setting`.  If you want to delete it, use `git config --unset` or `git config --unset-all`.<sup>1</sup>  Of course, if it's currently set to an unusable path, you get an error:

```
$ git config core.worktree /no/such/path
$ git config --get core.worktree
fatal: Invalid path '/no': No such file or directory
```

It might be nice if `git config` caught this problem internally and just avoided the attempt to `chdir` to the `core.worktree` path, but there's an easy workaround:

```
$ git --work-tree=. config --unset core.worktree
```

so unless/until someone modifies Git to avoid the early `fatal`, use the workaround.

---

<sup>1</sup>The only reason to use `--unset-all` is if there is more than one `core.worktree` setting.  Normally there would not be.

Comment: Accepted ! This answer and the explanations make sense (the command is as unintuitive as every other git commands, but at least it is a command :D)