# Git push succuess but files are not changed, why?

Tags: git, git-push

I created a repo, added the files, cloned it to my local machine, made changed, commited them, pushed them onto the Server but the changes are not in the files on the server.
My commands where the following:

On the server:

`git init`

`git add *`

`git commit`

I wrote the commit with initialize as comment.

Then i cloned it to my local machine using:

`git clone user@ipadresse:/path/to/.gitfolder`

I then noticed a little Problem with the Repo being non bare so I ran

`git config --bool core.bare true`

on the Server.

I created some folders and files in the repo localy added them and commited them.
I then pushed it onto the server and got the following output

```
Counting objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.83 KiB | 469.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 2), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ipadress:/path/to/.gitfolder
   881e1dc8..62ec93d9  master -> master
```

But the new files arent there.
When i run the command `git branch -a -v -v` on the Server I see the commit message from my local change.
So why isnt it changed on the Server and how do I get my updates there?

Comment: "Bare" repositories don't have any working copy.

Comment: By configuring the server repo to be bare, you effectively left a copy of the working directory that nothing ever updates. That means you should probably delete the working copy, to avoid confusion.

Comment: The whole idea of working directly on a remote git that is acting as the server seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Like most other `core` settings, `core.bare` is *descriptive* (describes the actual setup), not *prescriptive* (changing it does not change the actual setup).  So you should not just change it.  Just changing `core.bare` is like going out to a traffic light, taping over the red signal so that it never shows that you should stop, and making the green signal look always-lit-up so that you can always go.  It may even actually *work* for a while, until the eventual, inevitable traffic collision.

Normally, to make a bare clone—as needed to enable `git push`—you would use `git clone --bare`.  It *is* possible to convert a non-bare clone to a bare one (or vice versa); see [How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2199897/1256452) and note the "remove working copy" step.

If you want some<sup>1</sup> newly-`git push`-ed commits *automatically checked out* into a *non-bare* repository, see [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257982/1256452) to [cannot push into git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221859/1256452) (similarly in [pushing to a git repository does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191400/1256452)).

---

<sup>1</sup>For a description of what commits will or won't get deployed this way, see those answers and also [the Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receivedenyCurrentBranch).